# Setting a part of an element to a different color in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make this drop down menu where the button displayed space under the button is the same color. Though it's abit hard to describe in words this is what im trying to achieve. Though it works this is mostly for the design aspect of it.

```html
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin&display=swap');
      html,body{
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          background: #121212;
          height: 100%;
      }
      .main{
          height: 100%;
          width: 60%;
          margin:auto;
          background: #121212;
      }
      a,p,h1{
          font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
          color: white;
      }
      header{
          background: #181818;
          width: 100%;
          height: 75px;  
      }
      .headerMain{
          width: 60%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: auto;
          font-size: 40px;
          background-image: url(assets/Logo.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: right;
      }
      .headerMain a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 35px;
        display: block;
      }

      .headerMain a.icon {
          background: #121212;
          width: 60px;
          height: 55px;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
          padding-top: 20px;
          }

      .headerMain a:hover,i:hover{
        background-color: #282828;

      }

      nav{
          display:none;
          height: 50px;
          margin: 0;    
      }

      nav ul{
          background-color: #181818;
          list-style:none;
          margin:0;
          padding:10px;
          text-align:center;
      }
      nav li{
          display:inline;
      }
      nav a{
          font-weight: 900;
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 0 5px;
      }
      nav a:hover{
          background-color: white;
          color: black
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="headerMain">
            <a class="icon" onclick="dropDownFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav id="dropDown" >
        <ul>
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>Shop</a></li>
            <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
      function dropDownFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("dropDown");
          if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Desired Effect:

[image]

Comment: Your image seems the same as your code produces. Please add more details about what's not working

Comment: when the button is pressed, i want to try make it like the image itself. since the nav element is  background-color: #181818; but i want to make the part under the button     background: #121212;

Comment: Why simple don't use `background:trasparent` ?

Comment: That will effect the whole nav bar no? Im trying to have it only be a part of the nav bar to be that color.

Comment: @Yogi does this help? https://imgur.com/a/797MWdr

Comment: Just a tip for your next question, when debugging something with colors that are really alike, change them to something more obvious, like `red` and `blue`. We didn't understand what you were asking because the difference in colors is quite hard to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `:after` element that sits below the `icon` element.

Set the `background-color` to match the above `icon`.

I've added some more `padding-left` to the `nav ul` so that the first item does not overlap the new vertical bar

```css
.toToggle:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #121212;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin&display=swap');
      html,body{
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          background: #121212;
          height: 100%;
      }
      .main{
          height: 100%;
          width: 60%;
          margin:auto;
          background: #121212;
      }
      a,p,h1{
          font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
          color: white;
      }
      header{
          background: #181818;
          width: 100%;
          height: 75px;  
      }
      .headerMain{
          width: 60%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: auto;
          font-size: 40px;
          background-image: url(assets/Logo.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: right;
      }
      .headerMain a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 35px;
        display: block;
      }

      .headerMain a.icon {
          background: #121212;
          width: 60px;
          height: 55px;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
          padding-top: 20px;
          }

      .headerMain a:hover,i:hover{
        background-color: #282828;

      }

      nav{
          display:none;
          height: 50px;
          margin: 0;    
      }

      nav ul{
          background-color: #181818;
          list-style:none;
          margin:0;
          padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
          text-align:center;
      }
      nav li{
          display:inline;
      }
      nav a{
          font-weight: 900;
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 0 5px;
      }
      nav a:hover{
          background-color: white;
          color: black
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="headerMain">
            <a class="icon toToggle" onclick="dropDownFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav id="dropDown" >
        <ul>
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>Shop</a></li>
            <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
      function dropDownFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("dropDown");
          if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```